# Clicking on notification takes me to phone system settings instead of opening the application

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using Firebase functions to do the push notifications, and it works well. But after receiving notifications when I click on a certain type of notifications, it takes me to phone setting (Wifi setting, or application chooser dialog depending on phone I am testing on) instead of opening up the application. Below are my code for FirebaseMessagingService.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: url is " + remoteMessage.getData().get("avatar_url"));

    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
            .setLargeIcon(ImageManager.getBitmapFromUrl(remoteMessage.getData().get("avatar_url")));

    type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
    userName = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: username is " + userName);
    uid = remoteMessage.getData().get("uid");
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: uid is " + uid);
    chatId = remoteMessage.getData().get("chatId");
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: chatId is " + chatId);
    notificationId = remoteMessage.getData().get("notificationId");
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: notification id is " + notificationId);


    if(type.equals("message")){

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MESSAGING");
        resultIntent.putExtra("chatId", chatId);
        resultIntent.putExtra("uid", uid);
        resultIntent.putExtra("userName", userName);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        myRef.child("notifications")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child(notificationId)
                .setValue(null);

    } else {

        //Getting problem here

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        resultIntent.putExtra("FragmentIndicator", "2");

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        myRef.child("notifications")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child(notificationId)
                .setValue(null);

    }

    int mNotificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

}
```

For this logic `if(type.equals("message"))`, it all works fine. But the problem is with the `else` statement which includes notification types of friend request or friend request confirmation in which cases I am intent to direct users to my Chat Fragment.

My manifest for the main activity is like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any ideas what went wrong here? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are giving the system level intents to the pending intent so it's opening the system settings.
Instead, you should give your HomeActivity.class or any other activity from your application defined in the manifest of your application.

here you go.

```
 if(type.equals("message")){

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("chatId", chatId);
    resultIntent.putExtra("uid", uid);
    resultIntent.putExtra("userName", userName);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    myRef.child("notifications")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(notificationId)
            .setValue(null);

} else {

    //Getting problem here

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("FragmentIndicator", "2");

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    myRef.child("notifications")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(notificationId)
            .setValue(null);

}
```

Comment: happy coding :)